What is the correct folder structure for Python v2 Azure Functions?
I am working on the following Python v2 Azure Function:
azure function code with folder structure
The idea is to be able to call simple helper functions defined in shared_code/helper.py; helper.py has the following structure:
import logging
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def debug_print():
    return "whatever"

def here_using_requests():
    response = api_call()
    return response

When I deploy the code above, via GitHub, deployment is successful, but I cannot see any function in the Function App.

As soon as I remove from shared_code.helper import debug_print, function shows in the portal again, and it works (blob binders works fine).

Anyone who can explain to me what I am doing wrong and how can I correctly set up the project? Here's the other files of the azure function:
# host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

#requirements.txt

azure-functions
requests

Thanks!

I already tried to put helper.py out of the folder or to use different import statements, but issue persists.

Under the hypothesis that from shared_code.helper import debug_print is somehow interfering with the entry point of function_app.py, I did the following try: I moved import statement under main definition:


import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="BlobOutput1")
@app.route(route="file")
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob",
                path="product-data/xxx.csv",
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="product-data/test.csv",
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    from shared_code.helper import debug_print
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)

    string = debug_print()
    return string

In this case, deployment successful, I can see the function in the Function App, but when triggered I get a 500 internal error "no module named requests" (requests is correctly installed in the environment during deployment).
EDIT:
init.py is empty.
I have just made up api_call(), but you can assume it's something like:
def api_call():
    url = "https://api.xxx.com/auth/o2/token"
    payload = {
        "grant_type": "refresh_token"
    }
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json().get("access_token")


please share the code of api_call() and init.py

just added these info in the main question. init.py is empty and api_call() it's just any api call made via requests.

I have the same folder structure and code alike you and have used below given YAML code to deploy the function to function app using GitHub actions.
name: Deploy Python project to Azure Function App

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: 'afreeen-fa'   
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'       
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11'                    

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Pip'
      shell: bash
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"
        popd
    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }} 
        scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
        enable-oryx-build: true

This deployed my function successfully to function app.


You can also deploy the function either using func azure functionapp publish {functionAppName} command or function extension in vs code.

